# $p$-th moments and tail distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable. Then for the $p$-th moment $p\geq 0$ we have

$\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)=p\int_0^{+\infty}x^{p-1}\,\mathrm P(|X|\geqslant x)\,\mathrm dx
$

I am looking for the proof of this statement (a reference in the literature to a full proof is enough).

Comment: Think I got it: use representation as Riemann–Stieltjes integral and integrate by parts.

Comment: Got something from the answers below?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$|X|^p=p\int_0^{+\infty}x^{p-1}\,\mathbf 1_{|X|\geqslant x}\,\mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 4):

Since you also mentioned a reference to this fact, here is one: Theorem 1.13 in *Analysis* by Lieb and Loss (2nd edition, AMS). Key words: *layer cake representation*,

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** if $f$ and $X$ are positive, and $F(x) = P(X\le x)$ then
$$
Ef(X) = \int f(x) dF(x)
$$